# Is there a free implementation of SwiftForth SWOOP?

Tags: forth

Here: https://www.forth.com/product/swiftforth/ you can see that there is an object oriented version of forth available. Is there a free implementation with SWOOP support? I'm not afraid to build from source if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a portable version of SWOOP hosted on the [Forth Library Action Group](http://soton.mpeforth.com/flag/swoop/index.html).  It includes harnesses for VFX Forth and for SwiftForth, and - compared to the ASWOOP that comes with SwiftForth - most significantly lacks the `[OBJECTS ... OBJECTS]` local variable syntax.

I have harnesses that allow SWOOP to run on gforth and iforth as well.  You can find a version of the gforth harness [here](https://bitbucket.org/demonview/swoop/src).  These are fairly easy to make though, unless your Forth is very unusual.